# Getting an error with Twitter lib

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I have this snippet of code in my project to send a tweet ([also in jsBin](https://jsbin.com/maxujacofe/edit?js,output)):

```js
function sendTweet(status) {

  var twitterKeys= {
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "x",
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "x",
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "x",
    TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "x"    
  };

  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  props.setProperties(twitterKeys);
  twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

  var service = new Twitter.OAuth(props);


  if ( service.hasAccess() ) {

    var response = twit.sendTweet(status);

    if (response) {

      Logger.log("Tweet ID " + response.id_str);

    } else {

      // Tweet could not be sent
      // Go to View -> Logs to see the error message

    }
  }  
}

sendTweet("test");
```

But the problem I'm having is that I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "text" from undefined. (line 293, file "twitter", project "Twitter lib")
```

Line 293 is from version 21 of the ["Twitter lib" library](http://airhadoken.github.io/2015/06/29/twitter-lib-explained.html) ([MKvHYYdYA4G5JJHj7hxIcoh8V4oX7X1M_](https://script.google.com/d/MKvHYYdYA4G5JJHj7hxIcoh8V4oX7X1M_/edit)).

The message "test" actually gets tweeted, despite that error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Hi, author of Twitter Lib here. [@Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) pointed me here over Twitter.  I think I know what's going on with your script, and it's a peculiarity of how Google Script works.

You have most of your code in a function that takes an argument, and then you have a call to the function at the top level of your script.  What happens, when you go to the "Run" menu and select your `sendTweet` function, is that the script at the top level gets run **before the selected function is executed**, and the tweet would be sent at that time with the "test" text.

Then after that, `sendTweet` gets run with no arguments, meaning the `status` variable is `undefined`. You're sending an undefined value into `twit.sendTweet()`, causing the error you see.

What I'd recommend here is simply wrapping your last line of code into a function so you can call it from the Run menu, like this:

```js
function sendTestTweet() {
    sendTweet("test");
}
```

Comment: If you get any time to check out my question about Twitter lib over here I'd sure appreciate it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944948/what-parameters-will-twitter-libs-fetchtweets-method-accept

Answer (score 1):

Just to recap, the error you've seen is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "text" from undefined. (line 293, file "twitter", project "Twitter lib")

That is in the `sendTweet()` method of [the library](http://airhadoken.github.io/2015/06/29/twitter-lib-explained.html), see below.

```js
/**
* Upload a tweet to Twitter with optional media.
*
* @param {string | Tweet} tweet the status text to send as a Twitter update
* @param {optional object} params any additional parameters to send as part of the update post
* @return {object} the Twitter response as an object if successful, null otherwise
*/
OAuth.prototype.sendTweet = function(tweet, params) {
  var i;
  var payload = {       //<=== 293
    "status" : (tweet.text || tweet)
  };
```

Your code invokes this method with a single string parameter, `status`, which is set to "test".

The author of the library allowed for the `tweet` parameter to be one of two things:

- It can be an object with a `text` property containing the message to Tweet, or
- It can be a string.

However, the way that's being handled checks for `tweet.text` first, then if that does not exist it checks for a string `tweet`. When `tweet.text` does not exist (i.e. when using just a string), that TypeError is thrown.

I've reached out to the library author so they can publish the fix. However, in the meantime you can send a `Tweet` object with a `text` property, or take a copy of the library and update it yourself.

- **Send Tweet object.** The Tweet object is documented in the [Twitter API v1.1 documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets), but since the only property involved in this operation is `text`, a simple change in your `status` function will do the trick. Just ensure that `status` is an object with a `text` property.

  ```js
  function sendTweet(status) {
    if (typeof status === string)
      status = {text:status};
    ...
  ```
- **Update the library yourself.**
  To avoid the error, and handle the parameter options properly, line 294 in the library should be:

  ```js
  "status" : (tweet.hasOwnProperty("text") ? tweet.text : tweet)
  ```

  Or:

  ```js
  "status" : (typeof tweet === 'object' ? tweet.text : tweet)
  ```

  You'll need to publish it, and update the library ID in your code, but that should take care of this problem. Once a library update is available, you can switch back.

Comment: @user4411473 Thanks, but No - that's Amit's, he's not the library author.

Comment: Point of note: if ```status``` is null or undefined, ```hasOwnProperty``` would also trigger a runtime TypeError, and ```typeof null``` is ```"object"``` so your last code line wouldn't catch nulls.  Isn't JavaScript fun?